# Dúvida referente ao join com várias tabelas

Tags: java, jpa, persistência, eclipse-link

Tenho uma classe venda e a mesma recebe vários produtos(manyToOne) e cliente (oneToMany) e gostaria de juntar tudo em um join para fazer um relatório com apenas as informações desejadas.

Tentei me aventurar implementar mas deu Erro 500 no web service. Eu andei dando uma pesquisada e acredito que seja por causa que não adicionei @joinColumn mas mesmo assim não sei qual a serventia do mesmo

Entidade venda :

```
package entidade;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author 631520084
 */
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Venda implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String dtCompra;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Produto>produtos;
    @ManyToOne
    private Cliente cliente ;

    public Venda() {
    }

    public Venda(String dtCompra, List<Produto> produtos, Cliente cliente) {
        this.dtCompra = dtCompra;
        this.produtos = produtos;
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }



    public String getDtCompra() {
        return dtCompra;
    }

    public void setDtCompra(String dtCompra) {
        this.dtCompra = dtCompra;
    }

    public List<Produto> getProdutos() {
        return produtos;
    }

    public void setProdutos(List<Produto> produtos) {
        this.produtos = produtos;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Venda)) {
            return false;
        }
        Venda other = (Venda) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entidade.Venda[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Dao da venda e o join que usei que não funfou

```
*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rn;

import entidade.Fornecedor;
import entidade.Produto;
import entidade.Venda;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import util.Conexao;

/**
 *
 * @author 631520084
 */
public class VendaRN {


    public Venda inserir(Venda venda) {
        Conexao con = new Conexao();
        EntityManager em = con.getEntidade();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        for (Produto produto : venda.getProdutos()) {
            em.merge(produto);
        }
        em.merge(venda.getCliente());
        em.persist(venda);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return venda;
    }
    public List<Venda> relatorio() {
        Conexao con = new Conexao();
        EntityManager em = con.getEntidade();
        String jpql = "SELECT p.nome,c.nome, p.preco, v.dtCompra FROM Venda v JOIN v.cliente c JOIN v.produtos p";
        Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);
        List<Venda> listaVendas = query.getResultList();

        em.close();
        return (listaVendas);

    }

}
```

Erro

> HTTP Status 500 â€“ Internal Server Error Type Status Report
>
> Message Internal Server Error
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.30

OBS: o método inserir funciona por isso não é problema no webservice,o join esta compilando.

Answer (score 1):

O @JoinColumn serve para vc informar a coluna da tabela q referencia outra tabela. Por exemplo: se vc tem a tabela Venda, essa tabela deve ter uma coluna onde vc informar o cliente (clienteId por exemplo), então vc informaria:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="clienteId")
private Cliente cliente ;
```

No caso do OneToMany, normalmente vc informar a coluna na tabela referenciada, e depois informar a entidade, então em Produto você teria:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="vendaId")
private Venda venda;
```

E em Venda:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="venda") //aqui eu informei a propriedade na entidade Produto onde eu referenciei Venda
private List<Produto> produtos;
```

Sobre esse erro, esse é um erro genérico do tomcat. Pra saber o erro exato na sua aplicação você deve ver a mensagem de exceção no terminal ou dentro da IDE que vc usa, essa mensagem diz com mais precisão qual o erro no seu código.